# Paragraphs, lists, blockquotes with floating image

Tags: html, css

I have a simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            float: left;
            padding-left: 50px;
        }
        blockquote {
            background-color: #FF0;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/HTML.svg/200px-HTML.svg.png" />
        <p>
            paragraph
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
        <ol>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                blockquoted paragraph 
            </p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, appearance of the page is:

[image: The page with the image]

The same page without the image:

[image: The page without the image]

I have to get combination of the text alignment from the second example and the image floating to the left (the line of alignment is marked red):

[image: An ideal page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used display:inline as like this

```
<div>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/HTML.svg/200px-HTML.svg.png" />

     <div style="display:inline-block;">
     <p>
            paragraph
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
        <ol>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                blockquoted paragraph 
            </p>


        </blockquote>
</div>    
</div>​
```

Comment: i think you define ol, ul display table in css as like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/RntxN/2/

Answer (score 2):

Add left floated div to both image and other section.

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
    img {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
    blockquote {
        background-color: #FF0;
    } 
div {
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/HTML.svg/200px-HTML.svg.png"></div><div>
    <p>
        paragraph
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ol>
    <blockquote>
        <p>
            blockquoted paragraph 
        </p>
    </blockquote>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `DIV` with `float:left` for the text. See the [demo here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzWum/).

Comment: It's not a good solution for me, because I want to get a text alignment to the **div**'s left side below the image. And I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/RntxN/

Comment: Sorry I still may not have understood you correctly. Please see this [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzWum/2/) and verify if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add `margin-right: 50px;` to the img style...